# Rails.env returns 'development' in testing causing devise authenticity tokens to break tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, authentication, testing, devise

I started getting the following error consistently in my testing suite:

`NoMethodError: undefined method 'user' for nil:NilClass`

It seems to be from post requests I am making in the test suite.  Near the top of the stack trace was the following:

```
devise-2.1.2/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:259:in 'handle_unverified_request'
actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:78:in 'verify_authenticity_token'
```

This makes sense, because all I'm passing in my post request is an email, and not an authenticity token.  However, I feel like they should be handled by devise somehow.  I'm including `Devise::TestHelpers`, and I don't need to call sign_in to perform this request.

Upon further inspection, I found that if I `raise Rails.env.inspect`, I recieve "development".  Is that the reason that devise is expecting there to be authenticity tokens?  How can I force it to run in testing environment (I guessed and tried `$ rake test:functionals -e test` to no avail)?

The line that is causing this is

`post :forgot_password, {:user => { :email => users(:quentin).email }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was due to my tests running in development.  When I got it to run in the test environment, the errors went away.

The reason it wasn't running in the test environment is because I have been upgrading, and I had done a 'replace all' on `RAILS_ENV` with `Rails.env` and I had `ENV["Rails.env"]` listed in my test helper.  I guess rails was just ignoring this and defaulting to the development environment

Comment: For anyone else that runs into this error, I found that my database had been overwritten by my testing fixtures.  This might be an issue if you run tests in a server and the app thinks it's in production